# Nodejs MySQL ER_PARSE_ERROR on Insert Query errorno: 1064

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
app.post('', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('connected as id' + connection.threadID)
        const params = req.body;

        connection.query('INSERT INTO beers SET ?', [params], (err, rows) => {
            connection.release()

            if (!err) {
                res.send('Successfully added record of name' + params.name)
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })

        console.log(req.body)
    })
})
```

Comment: 1064 is syntax error. Provide **complete and unchanged** error message text. PS. Do you try to provide the SQL code fragment (column name, assignment operator and value) as a parameter?

Comment: nice! so, you give users the power to insert whatever they want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of library you're using to communicate with the DB, but I reckon, it should look more like

```
 connection.query('INSERT INTO beers(someColumn, someOtherColumn) VALUES (?,?)', [params.valueOfSomeColumn, params.valueOfSomeOtherColumn],...blabla the rest)
```

1. Looks like you're mixing up the INSERT and UPDATE statements. INSERT doesn't use SET
2. Usually this sort of basic DB libs connect the `?` characters with the value from an array